# Converting JSON date time to C# and ignoring timezone?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a scenerio where a user enters a date (ex 11/30/2018) from angular. When I parse this date from json into c# it comes in as 11/30/2018 4:00 or whatever timezone. This is good if I am in a timezone that -UTC like in America. If I have a user in India or Japan this is converted to 11/29/2018 5:30. Which is NOT good.

How can I convert the json and keep the date the user entered no matter which timezone the user resides in?

If a user enters 11/30/2018 in California and a user enters in 11/30/2018 in Japan the end result needs to be 11/30/2018 0:00 in both scenarios

this is my conversion code below

```
 strChangedData = [{\"EndDt\":\"2018-11-30T04:00:00.000Z\"}]

List<MyModel> objMyModel = (List<MyModel>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strChangedData, 
                           typeof(List<MyModel>), GetJsonSettings());  

public static JsonSerializerSettings GetJsonSettings()
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
                DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
                DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime
            };

            return settings;
        }
```

Comment: Can you implement your own `JsonConverter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually double check your dates coming in from your json code. I feel they may already have been converted in javascript.

Also change the jsonsettings to

```
public static JsonSerializerSettings GetJsonSettings()
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
                DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
                DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime
            };

            return settings;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `MyModel` to use DateTimeOffset if it is currently using DateTime.
You can get the Date using `.ToShortDateString()`, but it is possible you will inadvertently change the date if they user is in a different timezone if you aren't using DateTimeOffset.

Here is an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OA06L9

Answer (score 0):

You might have some success with [`IsoDatetimeConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter.htm).   I'd try something like this:

```
var isoDateConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" };

var objMyModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyModel>>(strChangedData, isoDateConverter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your user picked a date, you should not be sending back a date and time and time zone offset.  Just send the date:

```
{"EndDt":"2018-11-30"}
```

Then you don't need to change any of the date settings in the Json parser from their defaults.

Note that if your front-end is using `<input type="date">`, this is already given to you [in the `value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value).  You should not create a JavaScript `Date` object from the value.

If, however, you're using some other date picker control that only gives you back a `Date` object, then you'll need to pull the local year, month and date from it to construct the return string.  Libraries like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) can help, and some date pickers work with Moment natively.

Please provide more information about your date picker if you would like more specific advice in this regard.